# Questions about 'smoothly'

Tags: word-usage, meaning, word-request, expressions, collocations

1. Is there a difference between 'speak fluently' and 'speak smoothly' in meaning?
2. Is it correct to use 'smoothly' to describe 'speak English' such as 'He speaks English smoothly' and 'He speaks smoothly in English"?
3. Can 'really" go with 'smoothly' like 'speak really smoothly'?

Comment: There's been something of [a usage shift over the past century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speaks+fluent+English%2Cspeaks+English+fluently&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) - today we normally apply the adjectival form to the relevant language *(He speaks **fluent English**)*, rather than applying the adverb to the action *(He speaks **English fluently**)*.  And per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speaks+smooth+English%2Cspeaks+English+smoothly&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=), smooth/ly is rare.

Comment: Note that the collocation "smooth English" wouldn't really mean anything to most Anglophones. Also note that ***speaking smoothly*** isn't a common collocation - but ***smooth talking*** is, and that's all about being a convincing con-artist / trickster, nothing to do with verbal fluency as such.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, when people refer to their level in a certain language, the idiomatic technical word is ***[fluent](https://csb.uncw.edu/cen/docs/determining%20language%20proficiency.pdf)*** (or ***speak fluently***). ***Smooth*** is used more to describe the manner of speech rather than to assess the level of language proficiency. As in ***smooth-talker***:

> a person who gets another person to do their bidding by using a slick, gently persuasive, practised, or competent manner
>
> - He's such a smooth talker, he can persuade anyone to do anything. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/smooth-talker))

Being descriptive, ***smoothly*** can definitely be intensified. ***Fluent/fluently*** is more used in formal writing and often refers itself to a degree of knowledge (between *proficient* and *native*), and so it is not commonly intensified, at least in formal contexts. However, ***fluent/fluently*** is not restricted to this conotation, and this is where it overlaps with ***smooth/smoothly*** in meaning.

So both ***really smoothly*** and ***really fluently*** exist (though [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=really%20fluently%2Creally%20smoothly%2C%20really%20fluent%2C%20really%20smooth&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creally%20fluently%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creally%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creally%20fluent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creally%20smooth%3B%2Cc0) than *really smooth* and *really fluent*), but [more idiomatically](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%2A_VERB%20really%20fluently%2C%2A_VERB%20really%20smoothly&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwent_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgoing_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brun_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgo_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunning_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bruns_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgone_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgoes_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwent_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgoing_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brun_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgo_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brunning_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bruns_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgone_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bgoes_VERB%20really%20smoothly%3B%2Cc0) combined with other verbs than ***speak***:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The adjectives "smoothly" and "fluently" might be interpreted differently in different contexts.

For a native speaker, "fluently" might be understood to mean: "quickly, clearly, using complex and technical vocabulary precisely"  Whereas "smoothly might mean in a gentle flowing intonation."

For a learner "fluently" might be understood to mean "without hesitation" and be similar to "smoothly"

There is a little difference between "Speak English" and "Speak in English" that has been asked before, see if you can find the question. It is possible to use "really" but it is a weak modifier, and you can either omit or find a better adverb.

Comment: Do you mean "the adverbs smoothly and fluently"?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a difference between 'speak fluently' and 'speak smoothly' in meaning?

Wiktionary can shed some light on this:

[**Fluent**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fluent):

> In casual use, “fluency” refers to language proficiency broadly, while in narrow use it refers to using a language flowingly, rather than haltingly.

[**Smooth**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smooth):

> - [Glib](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glib) (Artfully persuasive but insincere in nature; smooth-talking, honey-tongued, silver-tongued.)
> - Flowing or uttered without check, obstruction, or hesitation; not harsh

That said, it also depends on the context. One *might* describe the manner of someone's speech as "fluent", synonymous with "smooth". However, it is much more common for the phrase "speak fluently" to refer to someone whose *proficiency* with a language is at or approaches the level of a native speaker. That is, someone might speak both "fluently" and with a very staccato, clipped voice which would hardly be described as "smooth".

In other words, "fluent" usually refers to one's *proficiency* with a language while "smooth" describes a particular tone of voice.

> Is it correct to use 'smoothly' to describe 'speak English' such as 'He speaks English smoothly' and 'He speaks smoothly in English"?

I would say it is unusual, at the least. Consider that an antonym might be "harshly". I suppose one might speak a particular language harshly (or smoothly), but usually there would not be a correlation between language and tone.

In any case, if your intent is to describe someone speaking with proficiency, with good pronunciation, and without hesitation due to being unsure about word choice, "fluently" would be a better choice than "smoothly".

> Can 'really" go with 'smoothly' like 'speak really smoothly'?

Maybe, but "very" is probably a better choice. (In fact, I believe this is true for adverbs in general, but there may be exceptions which are not immediately coming to mind. "Really" would more typically be used with a verb or adjective: "I'm *really* trying" or "the rock is *really* smooth". With adjectives, "very" often works equally well: "the rock is *very* smooth", with "really" likely coming across as less formal.) Note, however, that I would not typically expect to see "very *fluently*", as fluency (in the sense of proficiency) would not generally be qualified. One either possesses fluency, or does not.